# eclipse remote debug timeout problem

Tags: eclipse, jboss, remote-debugging

When I try to connect to remote server (jboss) that is on my local machine all works perfectly, but if I try to connect to remote machine (to jboss again) eclipse starts connecting and after some time tells me

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.
Timeout occurred while waiting for packet 1479.
```

but connection stays alive, and I have to kill it manually to reconnect again and get the connection time out error

How can I set timeout for remote debug, or may be there are other workarounds for such kind of problem?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can increase a value of debugging timeout in Eclipse.

Go to Window/Preferences. In the Java/Debug you'll see Debugger Timeout parameter.