# Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I tried to launch my eclipse debug(for server side code) i'm getting the following error Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

I did all the configuration of the post below but it still fails. What else can I do to debug the server side?

[Eclipse : Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620723/eclipse-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm-connection-refused)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the port and url are correct, you might want to check that a firewall (either on your local machine or on the remote host) isn't interfering with the debug.
Try to use the host's IP instead it’s name (to check for dns related problems).
you can also try to capture the tcp packets on the host (Wireshark is an excellent tool for that) to make sure that the packets are reaching the host. if so, it's a problem with the remote jvm's configuration, otherwise recheck the local configurations again.