# How to debug dynamic web page in Eclipse?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to debug my dynamic web application in Eclipse (Helios) as Debug mode but it could not work out. I have googled eventually i confirmed that i have to do Remote Debug. I trying to do Remote Debug. It seems doesn't work. Could please any one help me out to how to do set up Remote Debug and please mention steps to setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Error: "Failed to connect to remote VM"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975384/eclipse-error-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm)

Answer (score 0):

What app. server (web container) are you using ? I.e. tomcat , Add that server to your eclipse using "add server" and add project to it then run server in debug mode.

Comment: yes. i am using tomcat 6.0 and tried to run in debugg mode but it could not work out.

Comment: Are you able to run ur application without debug mode.

Comment: it is giving error as    "Lanching xxxxx(projectname) has encountred problem .Failed to connect remote VM.connection refused".What is remote debug .I am not getting what is remote debugg.

Comment: Mr. asad khan its working perfect on server and the issue is it is not running in debug mode

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620723/eclipse-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm-connection-refused) answer help you, If not then search specificaly the "Failed to connect remote VM.connection refused" in google your will find many solution hope any one will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its an issue with `port`.The port which you are trying to access is already occupied and wouldn't be released and you get this exception.Try restarting your system,in my case it worked.See the below post for more troubleshooting.

### See Also

- [Eclipse : Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620723/eclipse-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm-connection-refused)