# java - Eclipse Error: "Failed to connect to remote VM" Weblogic remote debugging using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jvm, weblogic-10.x

When ever i tried to launch my eclipse debug(Weblogic remote debugging using eclipse) i'm getting the following **error Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.**

Can anyone please provide me a solution on this ?? I am usind Eclipse Mars and JDK 1.7 and Weblogic server.

Comment: This question is already answered in the below forum [Answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620723/eclipse-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm-connection-refused)

Comment: not getting any suitable solution.

Comment: Make sure that you started the server first in debug mode. If that is done then check whether firewall is blocking that port

Comment: Its done after restarting the server and Eclipse both..!!